# Reference of R.java file in Android is not working

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I have this issue...

My android app has a settings menu to set an IP address and an image. I can validate the IP address with a regex and look up for the image in the root directory of my device, but the idea is that the image set by the user has to replace the default image in the main activity of the app... to do so, I declare an ImageView and initialized with the proper id (the one that contains the default image) from R.java file, and then replace it with the following instructions:

```
Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
Drawable dra = new BitmapDrawable(bmap);
imagen.setImageDrawable(dra);
```

Where imagen is the ImageView object. But for some reason, when I run this piece of code, logcat shows that imagen is null... that means, I'm getting a NullPointerException in the third line of the code above...

Here is the complete code of the settings menu activity:

```
public class pantallaConfiguracion extends Activity{
    private static final int REQUEST_PICK_FILE = 1;
    private EditText mFilePathTextView,ip;
    private Button mStartActivityButton, volver, guardar;
    private File selectedFile;
    private ImageView imagen;
    String dirIp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.configuraciones);
        ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entradaIP);
        volver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonVolver);
        guardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonGuardar);
        mFilePathTextView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entradaImg);
        mStartActivityButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonBrowse);
        imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen1);
        volver.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        guardar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dirIp = ip.getText().toString();
                if(validarIp(dirIp) == false){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dirección IP incorrecta.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Main.IP_Server = dirIp;
                    descargarDatos.IP_Server = dirIp;
                    enviarDatos.IP_Server = dirIp;
                    Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    Drawable dra = new BitmapDrawable(bmap);
                    imagen.setImageDrawable(dra);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cambios Efectuados Correctamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            private boolean validarIp(String dirIp) {
                String patron = "(([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}\\.)|(2[0-4][0-9]\\.)|(25[0-5]\\.)){3}(([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))";
                Pattern expreg = Pattern.compile(patron);
                Matcher m;
                m = expreg.matcher(dirIp);
                if(m.matches() == false){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        mStartActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.botonBrowse:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(pantallaConfiguracion.this, FilePicker.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PICK_FILE:
                if(data.hasExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH)) {
                    selectedFile = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePicker.EXTRA_FILE_PATH));
                    mFilePathTextView.setText(selectedFile.getPath());              
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the logcat output:

```
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at tian.proto.pantallaConfiguracion$2.onClick(pantallaConfiguracion.java:73)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-02 13:40:17.671: E/AndroidRuntime(3139):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!!

Comment: ready, I posted logcat

Comment: What is line no 73 in the above code..?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint there to verify that the `ImageView` is `null` and not `dra`?

Comment: I would guess that the "imagen1" view does no exist in the layout. Could you post the configuraciones.xml as well?

Comment: line 73 is imagen.setImageDrawable(dra);

Comment: The error is in this your bitmap is null, **Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());**

Comment: i did it by putting Log.e(dra) and Log.e(imagen), logcat shows that the null one is imagen

Comment: @alois.wirkes is your layout contain imageview with the id imagen1?

Comment: koljaTM, you mean that in one activity I can not reference objects from another activity layout?

Comment: @alois.wirkes yes you can not..in order to get the object from another layout, you need to inflate the layout and you need to get that

Comment: yes indeed, i just verified that by putting an imageview element in the layout configuraciones.xml and worked just fine, now i have to get the object from the other layout, i don't know how but i have to... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the imageview in the main activity from the settings activity. What you could do is save the image path in a SharedPreference and then e.g. in the onResume() method of your main activity see if the property is set and then instantiate the image accordingly. You might need to add some caching or so to avoid unnecessary loading.